# datepicker in android - get month and day as MM -DD

Tags: android, datepicker, date-format, getdate

I am developing an android app which uses datepicker. when i use :

```
request.addProperty("datetext",datePicker.getYear()+"-"+(datePicker.getMonth()+1)+"-"+datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
```

I am getting the output as 2013-1-7 for **7 jan 2013**

But how can i get the output as  2013-01-07 for the same.

Comment: read the doc, the use is pretty straight forward

Answer (score 4):

thanks all... i got the solution...

```
Integer month = datePicker.getMonth()+1;
Integer day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
request.addProperty("datetext",datePicker.getYear()+"-"+((month.toString().length()   == 1 ? "0"+month.toString():month.toString()) )+"-"+((day.toString().length() == 1 ? "0"+day.toString():day.toString())));
```

so this will show **months** as **01 02 03 04....10 11 12**  and **days** as **01 02 03....10 11.......**

Answer (score 1):

```
Date yourDate= new Date(datePicker.getYear(), (datePicker.getMonth()+1), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
```

You can use `SimpleDateFromat` as below:

```
String strDate = null;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
strDate = dateFormatter.format(yourDate);
```

So you will get date in format you want (yyyy-MM-dd).

Edit:

For changing dates with change in datepicker you can try as follows:

```
datePicker.init(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, new OnDateChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
                    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Date selectedDate = new Date(datePicker.getYear(), (datePicker
                        .getMonth() + 1), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
                String strDate = null;
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
                strDate = dateFormatter.format(selectedDate);
            }
        });
```

So you will find the updated date as and when date picker will change.

Comment: i need the dates to be changed with change in datepicker

Comment: @user1945090, you can use OnDateChangedListener() for that purpose. Check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
java.util.Date date = null;
try 
{
date = form.parse("2013-01-7T09:39:01.607");
}
catch (ParseException e) 
{

e.printStackTrace();
}
SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String newDateStr = postFormater.format(date);
```

Comment: but does the date change when i change the date in the datepicker?

Comment: The picker take the date format chosen by the user, which means you can use the format you wish to use. So try it out! I suppose it should allow you to.